# After downloading whole (84M) file from dropbox it turning into 0 bytes

Tags: java, inputstream, dropbox, outputstream

I am downloading a zip file from dropbox. When it keeps downloading I measure the file size and get it is increasing its size with the  Below code. It downloads whole 84M and after finishing download it turns into 0 bytes. What wrong am I actually doing?

```
public static void downloadDropBox(File file) {

    String url = "https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jx4b2wvqg8d4ze1/AAA0J3LztkRc6FJ5tKy4dUKha?dl=1";

      int bytesRead;
      byte[] bytesArray = new byte[1024];
      InputStream is = null;
      FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
      long progres = 0;

    try {
        URL fileUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)fileUrl.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        is = connection.getInputStream();
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        while ((bytesRead = is.read(bytesArray, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytesArray, 0, bytesRead);

            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (outputStream != null) {
            try {
                outputStream.flush();

                outputStream.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

During download file:

[image]

After Finishing download file:

[image]

Comment: Please, attach your call to downloadDropbox method

Comment: I can't get you. What do you mean by attach my call ?

Comment: Somewhere you have to call that method to use it..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170525/discussion-between-rcordoval-and-amir).